# Update react Context from children or alter component structure?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

**This question focuses on the Header component:**
 So in my app. I have a something that looks a bit like this with a few more components and plenty more routes:

```
return (
        <SiteLayoutContext.Provider value={siteConfiguration} >
            <div className="topContainer">

                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div className="header">
                        <Header/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="mainWrapperContainer">
                        <div className="contentWrapper">

                            <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
                            <Route exact path='/home' component={Home}/>
                            <Route exact path='/about' component={About}/>
                            <Route exact path='/collection/:collectionName' component={CollectionLandingPage}/>
                            <Route exact path='collection/:collectionAlias/id/:itemId' component={ItemView}/>
                        </div>
                        <Footer/>
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>

        </SiteLayoutContext.Provider>
    )
```

**What I'd like to accomplish:** 

I can currently set a logo for the header. 
This is great, but I'd like the user to be able to select a custom logo, one that will replace the global default, if they are *within* a collection.

**To define 'within' a collection**, the route will start with `/collection/` so in the example below, both the `ItemView` and the `CollectionLandingPage` should have this custom logo.

I need to be able to tell my header that it's currently within a collection, and I want to limit renders and redraws to improve performance. I have an api endpoint that I fetch to grab collection info, which would tell me if a custom logo has been set, and what the href should be.

**What I've tried:** 
My original thought was to rip the header out of the main `return()` shown above, and instead place it within every component, that way I can use React's `useLocation()` hook to check the the url, and only fetch the collection's logo if
1) we're within a collection and 
2) a custom logo has been set.

My issue with this method is that I now have to enter the Header within every single component, instead of how it is currently implemented.

**My second thought is to wrap it all within some kind of context**, consume it in every component, and update it based on the url, which would then fetch the relevant info, but this just feels *off*. I suppose I could fetch the information for the collection and update a new CollectionInfoContext every time I hit `/collection/:collectionName` which would only update when the `collectionName` changes?

**I'm kind of just looking for suggestions on how to implement this** because well... I feel like there's an option I haven't listed that's probably much easier and more reasonable... as is the stackoverflow standard.

Disclaimer: I'm a react context api novice

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Redux or another state management solution, a context is definitely a reasonable way to share data across your application, UI themes are actually one of the [recommended use cases](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) in the React docs.

The only issue I could see is that changing the state for only certain components would require a way of resetting the context for other places where you just want a standard logo.  But reading the URL name could solve that by simply storing the path name and using it inside of `Header` to render the custom logo if the path includes `collections`.  If `Header` can read the path name all on its own, you may not even need a context if that's the only condition that's dynamic everywhere.